# (How to set) / (can't see) the cursor on a Textfield in Libgdx?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, textfield

I have tried to create a drawable (ninepatch) and in textfieldstyle done this

```
greenTextFieldStyle.cursor = getSkin().getDrawable("textFieldCursor1");
```

But I can't see any cursor...

This is the current cursor image, I have also tried a 1 * 20 image without success.

[image: It's really small]

it's basically a 3 * 3 image, with a + in the middle and points outside for the ninepatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getSkin().newDrawable("textFieldCursor1",Color.green)` and add a min width to it `greenTextFieldStyle.cursor.setMinWidth(2f);`

here a compleat Skin inclusive "selectionframe":

```
Skin skin = new Skin();
skin.add(
        "background",
        new NinePatch(this.game.manager.get("hud/ninepatchframe.png",
                Texture.class), 5, 5, 5, 5));
skin.add("cursor", this.game.manager.get("data/cursor.png"));

TextFieldStyle tStyle = new TextFieldStyle();
tStyle.font = getDefaultFont(25); //here i get the font
tStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;
tStyle.background = skin.getDrawable("background");
tStyle.cursor = skin.newDrawable("cursor", Color.GREEN);
tStyle.cursor.setMinWidth(2f);
tStyle.selection = skin.newDrawable("background", 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f);

this.nameField = new TextField("enter name here", tStyle);
```

---

Here how i get the Bitmap Font. I am using the [extansion from libgdx](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300) to create it from a `.ttf`. 
Take a look at the link how to add the nativ files.

Here the code how to use it:

```
public BitmapFont getDefaultFont(int size) {
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.ttf"));
    defaultFont = generator.generateFont(size + 5); //some offset
    return defaultFont;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the setMinWidth(2f); did it for me! Also, I can see you're using some sort of method to get default font with a size, how do you set the size for a bitmapfont?

Comment: Added it into the answer. I am using the `gdx-freetype` extansion. The code might be outdate. My game is working with 9.7.x if i remember that right

Comment: Thanks, will check it out! Could you help answering this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318030/cant-draw-a-ninepatch-image-and-stage-at-the-same-time