# Can't draw a ninepatch image and stage at the same time

Tags: java, libgdx, stage

Whenever I try to draw a ninepatch image and a stage the last thing that's called is being drawn. I have tried to use a orthographic camera but didn't succeed. What I have tried:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
ninePatch.draw(batch, xPos, yPos, width, height);
stage.act(delta);
stage.draw();

camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
stage.setCamera(camera)
```

EDIT: The code

The CreateQuiz class

```
public class CreateQuiz implements Screen{

    public CreateQuiz(Quiz quiz){
    this.quiz = quiz;
    }

    private Quiz quiz;
    private FallDownPanel fallDownPanel;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    quiz.beginBatch();
    fallDownPanel.render(quiz.getSpriteBatch(), delta);
    quiz.endBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    fallDownPanel = new FallDownPanel(FallDownPanel.START_LOWER_SIDE, 200, quiz.getTextureAtlas().createPatch("fallDownWindow"));
    Stage stage = new Stage(fallDownPanel.getWidth(), fallDownPanel.getHeight(), false);
    TextFieldStyle style = quiz.getGreenTextFieldStyle();
    style.font.scale(-0.30f);
    TextFieldQuiz test = new TextFieldQuiz("Hej åäö 123 !", style, 0, 2, 400, 16);
    test.setTextFieldListener(new TextFieldListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped (TextField textField, char key) {
        if (key == '\n') {
            textField.getOnscreenKeyboard().show(false);
        }
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(test);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    fallDownPanel.setStage(stage);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    stage.setCamera(camera);
    fallDownPanel.setCamera(camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

The FallDownPanel.class

```
    public class FallDownPanel {

    //With repeat
    public FallDownPanel(int startSide, int size, NinePatch ninePatch){
    Tween.registerAccessor(FallDownPanel.class, new FallDownPanelTween());
    Tween.registerAccessor(Widget.class, new WidgetTween());
    tweenManager = new TweenManager();
    final int screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    final int screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    int target = 0;
    int tweenType = 0;

    if(startSide == START_LEFT_SIDE){
        setSize(size, screenHeight);
        xPos = -size;
        yPos = 0;
        target = 0;
        tweenType = FallDownPanelTween.POSITION_X;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_RIGHT_SIDE){
        setSize(size, screenHeight);
        xPos = screenWidth;
        yPos = 0;
        target = screenWidth - size;
        tweenType = FallDownPanelTween.POSITION_X;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_UPPER_SIDE){
        setSize(screenWidth, size);
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = screenHeight + size;
        target = screenHeight - size;
        tweenType = FallDownPanelTween.POSITION_Y;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_LOWER_SIDE){
        setSize(screenWidth, size);
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = -size;
        target = 0;
        tweenType = FallDownPanelTween.POSITION_Y;
    }

    Tween.to(this, tweenType, 1).target(target).start(tweenManager);
    this.tweenType = tweenType;
    this.startSide = startSide;

    this.ninePatch = ninePatch;
    }

    private TweenManager tweenManager;
    private NinePatch ninePatch;
    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private float xPos, yPos;
    private int width, height;
    private int tweenType;
    private int startSide;
    public static final int START_LEFT_SIDE = 0, START_RIGHT_SIDE = 1, START_UPPER_SIDE = 2, START_LOWER_SIDE = 3;

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float delta){
    tweenManager.update(delta);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    ninePatch.draw(batch, xPos, yPos, width, height);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    }

    public void setX(float x){
    this.xPos = x;
    }

    public void setY(float y){
    this.yPos = y;
    }

    public float getX(){
    return xPos;
    }

    public float getY(){
    return yPos;
    }

    public float getWidth(){
    return width;
    }

    public float getHeight(){
    return height;
    }

    private void setSize(int w, int h){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;
    startWidgetTweens();
    }

    private void startWidgetTweens(){
    float size = getShortestSide();
    Array<Actor> actors = stage.getActors();
    for(int i = 0; i < actors.size; i++){
        Widget w = (Widget) actors.get(i);
        Tween.to(w, tweenType, 1).target(0).start(tweenManager);
    }
    }

    private float getShortestSide() {
    if(startSide == START_LEFT_SIDE){
        return width;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_RIGHT_SIDE){
        return width;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_UPPER_SIDE){
        return height;
    }

    else if(startSide == START_LOWER_SIDE){
        return height;
    }

    return -1;
    }

    public void setCamera(OrthographicCamera camera) {
    this.camera = camera;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the ninepatch to the Stage as Actor and it should be fine. The right order is important if you render stuff. It could be possible that you overdraw everything with the ninePatch/stage thats why you dont see anything else. Please do add the whole render method

Comment: @BennX Can you make the background of a stage transparent?

Comment: I solved it, I stopped the current batch, because stage has it's own batch, or something like that. Then I just called stage.act() and stage.draw(); Thank you @Bennx

Comment: Oh yea forgot that. Had the same issue with an tiled map. The stage has it's own sprite batch and if you have two active they are concurring and that causes troubles.

Comment: Solved your issue? If it is solved please post the solution as an answer and mark it as correct to help others with the same issue. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you have only one active `Renderer` at a time. The `Renderer`s are:

- `Batch`
- `SpriteBatch`
- `ShapeRenderer`
- `Box2DDebugRenderer` if i am not wrong
- `ModelBatch` for 3D

I hope i did not forget one.
Make sure you always call `end()` for the active one, before calling `begin()` for a new one.
Also remember, that a `Stage` has its own `SpriteBatch` and it calls `begin()` for this `SpriteBatch`, if you call `stage.draw()`. So make sure you `end()` the active `Renderer`, before `stage.draw()`.
If you need a `ShapeRenderer` or any other renderer to draw an `Actor` (maybe cause of debuging), you have to end the `stage`s `SpriteBatch`, which you get with the `draw()` method. Make sure you `begin()` it again at the end of the method.
Hope this is clear enough.